# Vim search and replace to amend a string with common structure but varying words

Tags: vim, vi

I'm fairly new to Vim and I haven't been able to find on this site how to search and replace with a varying part of a string. I need to apply a global edit to all times "`SetTag("...")`" appears with `...` being **any** word. My edit is to add one more word **after** the *second* quotation mark. example: SetTag("err" **+ __LINE__** with the bolded part being what I need to add. Can anyone let me know how this is possible with a vim search command? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nb: I assume "word" is any sequence of characters other than a doublequote character. Modify as needed.

```
:%s/SetTag("\([^"]*\)")/SetTag("\1" + __LINE__)/
```

the escaped parentheses grab the sub-match; the \1 in the replacement string is replaced by that sub-match.

Comment: You are right that the "word"s I have are letters and *not* doublequote characters but that did not work for me. 
This gives me `Pattern not found: SetTag("\([^"]*\)")`  
The "word" varies between many different tag categories. By "Modify as needed" do you mean I need to enter each word individually or it would catch all words? (I am looking for a catch all.)  
  
for reference this is the exact command I ran  
`%s/SetTag("\([^"]*\)")/SetTag("\1 line: " + std::to_string(__LINE__)/`

Comment: The modify part was just what constitutes a word. In my case I used `[^"]*` to select any string of zero or more non-doublequote characters. The part inside the `\(...\)` is the word, the rest is supposed to be the exact surrounding text.

Comment: If it didn't match, try just searching for it with `/` to see what parts match and when it stops matching. Maybe there's an extra space or something in your target text.

Comment: Ah I see, what broke the command I ran above was the close parenthesis when I didn't need one. Worked perfectly, thanks!